# web-component slot content is not displayed

Tags: web-component, svelte, custom-element

I'm building a custom-element using svelte. Below is svelte component content

```
<template>
    <slot name="description">{ description }</slot>
    <slot name="days">
        { padTime(Math.max(time.days, 0)) }
    </slot>
    <slot name="hours">
        { padTime(Math.max(time.hours, 0)) }
    </slot>
    <slot name="minutes">
        { padTime(Math.max(time.minutes, 0)) }
    </slot>
    <slot name="seconds">
        { padTime(Math.max(time.seconds, 0)) }
    </slot>
</template>
```

While time related slot are well updated, for some reason, description slot is not.

It is well updated in the shadow DOM, but not displayed:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The content you put inside a slot is the fallback content for that slot -- it is only displayed if nothing is passed to the slot. In your example, you are putting `<div slot="description">Test</div>` in the description slot so the fallback "Presale starts in" is not displayed. For the other slots, you are not passing content into them, so they display the fallback content.

You might not need to use slots here at all if you always want the content inside the component to be displayed and don't want to pass in any elements from outside the component.

```html
<template>
    <div>{ description }</slot>
    <div>
        { padTime(Math.max(time.days, 0)) }
    </div>
    <div>
        { padTime(Math.max(time.hours, 0)) }
    </div>
    <div>
        { padTime(Math.max(time.minutes, 0)) }
    </div>
    <div>
        { padTime(Math.max(time.seconds, 0)) }
    </div>
</template>
```

Comment: Ok, that's probably my bad, I kinda tried to "violate" the purpose of web-components. My goal is to make a component that handles the logic while the CSS styling and html arrangements are done where the component is used. Is this doable somehow ?

Comment: @Syffys the purpose of a component is to encapsulate a feature and use them over and over. Perhaps consider reading Google and MDN's docs esp re best practices https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-components/best-practices this is a shot in the dark at understanding your question as comment. Perhaps post a question in https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/ or some more specific question. HTH